# Как вставить переменную в sql запрос php?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть код:

```
 $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM  `bossinfo` WHERE  `idboss` LIKE  '8BThqpo8yvRB02N'
  ORDER BY  `bossinfo`.`ipa` ASC LIMIT 0 , 30");
```

Как вместо **8BThqpo8yvRB02N** вставить переменную **$fstr** ?
Пробовал по разному, с разными кавычками, но бестолку. Скрипт ничего не выдает = ничего не печатает, хотя если оставить так как есть, то все в порядке.

Comment: я бы так делать не советовал, но почему бы не сделать просто

    $query = "SELECT * FROM  bossinfo WHERE  idboss LIKE '$fstr' ORDER BY bossinfo.ipa ASC LIMIT 0 , 30";


если это не сработает, то $fstr не задана, либо задана неправильно.

Comment: решил так 
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM  `botinfo` WHERE  `idbot` LIKE trim('$fstr')
          ORDER BY  `botinfo`.`ip` ASC LIMIT 0 , 30");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще лучше использовать `PDO` или `MySQLi` и `bind`-ить значения. Пример `mysqli`

```
   if ($result = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM  `bossinfo` WHERE  `idboss` LIKE  ? ORDER BY  `bossinfo`.`ipa` ASC LIMIT 0 , 30"))
        {
            $result->bind_param('s',$fstr);
            $result->execute();
            $result->close();
        }
```

.