# Ошибка 1064 в PHP при использовании MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, веб-программирование, phpmyadmin

```
        <?php

if( isset($_POST['']) && isset($_POST['']) ){
    $code=$_POST[''];   
    $name=$_POST[''];   
    // Соединяемся, выбираем базу данных
    $query = "INSERT INTO AndroidHelper (name,code) VALUES ('$name','$code')";

    mysql_query($query);
    echo mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link). "\n";
    // Закрываем соединение
    mysql_close($link);
}

?>  


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Добавление файла</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

</head>
<body>

    <form action="addFile.php" method="POST">
        Название: <input type="text" name="name" style="width: 200px;"><br>
        <p>Код:</p><textarea rows="100" cols="150" name="code"></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" style="padding: 10px" value="Добавить"/>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

### Текст который добавляю

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.4'


DurationFormatUtils.formatDuration(Integer.valueOf(trackBean.duration) * 1000, "mm:ss", true);
```

Если обычный текст добавлять то работает все.

### А так выглядит код ошибки

```
1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.4' DurationFormatUt' at line 1
```

Comment: Логично. вы вставляете строку с кавычками. в итоге выходит `insert ... vales('abc'def', ...)` кавычки из строки ломают запрос. типичный случай SQL-инъекции. _Никогда_ не подставляйте значения переменных непосредственно в текст запроса. Используйте (вместо устаревшего еще 5 лет назад) mysql_* расширения mysqli или PDO и подготавливаемые выражения с привязкой переменных. http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: @Mike Может имеет смысл создать а-ля wiki-пост и использовать его совместно с "дубликат вопроса"? А то почти каждый день одни и те же грабли

Comment: Просто я попробовал тоже самое сделать в PhpMyAdmin. И данная строка добавилась. Без проблемм.

Comment: @EraNewGames вероятно в phpmyadmin вы заэкранировали кавычки или если вставляли через окошечко интерфейса она отлична вставилась потому что phpmyadmin использует правильные техники работы с БД и заботится об экранировании если приходится работать через mysql_

Comment: @Mike, Да я через интерфейс добавил. Не через консоль

Comment: @Mike, Получается мне надо вместо `mysql_query` использовать `mysqli_query`. Думаю это не поможет ))

Comment: @EraNewGames поможет. если помимо другой функции будете писать запрос в виде `insert into ... values(?,?)` а потом привязывать переменные к этим вопросительным знакам. так и БД быстрее работает и вас через день после выкатки приложения на бой не взломают

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
$name = mysql_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$code = mysql_escape_string($_POST['code']);

$query = "INSERT INTO AndroidHelper (name,code) VALUES ('" . $name . "','" . $code . "')";
```

З.Ы. Используйте mysqli или PDO mySQL.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не советуйте использовать устаревшие функции (разве что в крайнем случае, после нормального ответа по pdo/mysqli), тем более что таких ответов на сайте по паре в месяц и по дублю проще вопрос закрыть.

Comment: то что вы скинули это misqli?

Comment: mysqli, спс, поправил

Comment: `Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in add1File.php on line 6 Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in add1File.php on line 6 Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in add1File.php on line 7 Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in add1File.php on line 7`

Что - то пошло не так)

Comment: тогда используйте mysql_escape_string, поправил в ответе

Comment: Спасибо)).  А что mysql_real_escape_string не заработала потому что php старое наверное?

Comment: Ну вот видите, человек с этими советами кинулся использовать real_escape, а через пару лет, когда он уже успеет написать много кода вдруг окажется что часть хостингов просто отказались от поддержки mysql_ и ему придется все переписывать. @EraNewGames нет, то что тут советуют это не mysqli. у него все функции начинаются на приставку mysqli_, а не mysql_ и посмотрите по ссылке, что я вам сбросил изначально. Там в конце есть примеры

Comment: нет, mysql_real_escape_string() учитывает кодировку символов, а mysql_escape_string нет. тут вам надо почитать хотя бы это: https://php.ru/manual/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.html

Comment: Товарищъ Mike абсолютно правильно вам замечает в комментариях. Почему-то 80% таких вопросов вращаются вокруг mysql. Расширение уже нигде не используется. Может только на саппорте динозавров.

Comment: @KirillKorushkin, Потому что в инете сайты остаются на mysql. Интернет это как некий мусор, Время идет, а мусор не убирают за собой. А гуглы и яндексы быстрее дают ответы на вопросы из старых сайтов.... Ладно буду учить mysqli. Вроде он почти не отличается от mysql

Comment: @Mike, А если я буду использовать mysqli. То мне все равно надо mysql_escape_string исопльзовать?
или так тоже прокатит уже? `$name = $_POST['name'];`

Comment: @EraNewGames вопрос лишь в том _как_ использовать. вот например правильная техника https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/301718/194569 вы в тексте запроса ставите `?` вместо всех передаваемых параметров. после чего выполняете bind значения. в этом случае никакое экранирование не нужно, так как значения идут в БД отдельно от текста запроса. А в  PDO это еще и короче. там запрос готовится так же с `?`, а потом выполняется как `->execute( array($name,$code) )` т.е. параметры передаются как параметры